# MySQL Connector for Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am using `mysql.connector` for Python. Below are my connection parameters. How can I set a timeout or increase the default timeout?

```
class Config(object):
    """Configure me so examples work

    Use me like this:

        mysql.connector.Connect(**Config.dbinfo())
    """

    HOST = dbhost
    DATABASE = dbdatabase
    USER = dbusername
    PASSWORD = dbpassword
    PORT = 3306

    CHARSET = 'utf8'
    UNICODE = True
    WARNINGS = True

    @classmethod
    def dbinfo(cls):
        return {
            'host': cls.HOST,
            'port': cls.PORT,
            'database': cls.DATABASE,
            'user': cls.USER,
            'password': cls.PASSWORD,
            'charset': cls.CHARSET,
            'use_unicode': cls.UNICODE,
            'get_warnings': cls.WARNINGS,
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MySQL Connector/Python :: 6 Connector/Python Connection Arguments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) in the official documentation:

> To set a timeout value for connections, use `connection_timeout`.

Comment: The Python documentation doesn't specify. The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_connect_timeout) specifies "seconds", so I'd _guess_ the same, but would measure myself to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `mysql.connector.connect` to connect with DB you can simply use `connection_timeout` parameter to define a timeout externally make sure value given will be in `seconds` instead of milliseconds.

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    pool_name=pool['name'], 
    pool_size=pool['size'],
    host=config['host'], 
    port=config['port'], 
    user=config['user'],
    passwd=config['passwd'],
    db=config['db'],
    charset=config['charset'], 
    use_unicode=True,
    connection_timeout=10
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-python-connectargs.html
I think you are looking for the parameter 
         connection_timeout (connect_timeout*)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    pool_name=pool['name'], 
    pool_size=pool['size'],
    host=config['host'], 
    port=config['port'], 
    user=config['user'],
    passwd=config['passwd'],
    db=config['db'],
    charset=config['charset'], 
    use_unicode=True,
    connect_timeout=1000
)
```

If you use MySQLdb:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(
    host=config['host'], 
    port=config['port'], 
    user=config['user'], 
    passwd=config['passwd'],
    db=config['db'], 
    charset=config['charset'], 
    use_unicode=True,
    connect_timeout=1000
)
```

Comment: What's the unit? Seconds?